# How to iterate through columns and rows in excel with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

I am a self-taught beginner “””coder”””. For a bigger script I am writing, I need to write a function that checks if the input of the user exists in an excel file in a column (say) A and, if it does, return the value of the same row in column (say) B.

[Screenshot of a sample excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSy2d.png)

In the above picture, I would check if the input is Seth I will return 500, if it is John I will return 800, etcetera.

I am finding xlrd and pandas docs very confusing. I am blocked between ifs and for loops. This is a mixture between the pseudocode and Python I am thinking of.

```
listA = column A
listB = column B
for i in listA:
    if input in listA:
        return i.listB
```

I imagine something like that but I cannot put it to work. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Are you having trouble reading the excel file? Parsing the DataFrame in Pandas? Something else?

Comment: My first trouble is: how to check if the input is in a column of excel. This includes reading a specific column and (guess) iterating through all its elements. I think overcoming that would push me forward to the end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be a lookup dictionary which stores all the values in Column A and their according values on Column B, so you can speedily look them up whenever you need the value for a given key.
At least this would be a good idea for small files. If the lookup takes up too much memory, you would have to revert to scanning the excel file.

To use a dictionary, just load the excel table and collate the two columns of interest to a dictionary. Then, you can use a try-except block to retrieve the values or output an error message.

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_excel("example.xlsx")
lookup = dict(zip(data["Names"],data["Values"]))

n = input("\nEnter the name: ")

try:
    print("The value is: "+str(lookup[n]))
except:
    print("There is no such name in the file")
```

I did it with an excel file that resembles yours and got the answers:

```
Enter the name: John
The value is: 800

Enter the name: Peter
The value is: 354

Enter the name: William
The value is: 132

Enter the name: Fritz
There is no such name in the file

Enter the name: Santa
There is no such name in the file
```

Comment: I think this is great. One more question: how big is a small file? Could I use it for (say) 100 elements for each column? My actual file is about 40 elements each column.

Comment: A 'small file' in this respect would be a file that is smaller than, say, 100MB. I currently use this technique to sort through CSVs with 60'000 to 200'000 entries. So, 100 rows are perfectly fine.

Comment: Never use an unqualified `except` clause.